# How to drop the column of a data frame that contain at least one missing element

Tags: python, pandas

I simulate a data frame as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create Missing Values in DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,5))
df[df > 0.9] = pd.np.nan
df.columns = ['A', 'B','C','D','E']
df
```

which i gave a column name as A, B, C, D, E. I have this python code to remove rows that contain at least one missing value through pandas as follows"

```
df.loc[(~pd.isnull(df['A']))&\
   (~pd.isnull(df['B']))&\
   (~pd.isnull(df['C']))&\
   (~pd.isnull(df['D']))&\
   (~pd.isnull(df['E']))]
```

How can I achieve removing column(s) instead of row(s) that contain at least one missing value in any of its rows and also in a specific row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider boolean selection

```
df.loc[:, ~df.isnull().any(axis=0)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `df.dropna()` to remove rows/columns that contain NaNs. Read more https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) while specifying `axis`:

```
df = df.dropna(axis='columns', how='any')
```

The default for `how` is `'any'`, but you can be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isnull()` and `drop`:

```
for i in df.columns:
    if df[i].isnull().count() > 0:
        df = df.drop(i, axis=1)
```